# Htaccess rewrite for .pdf to php file not working with chrome

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, pdf

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.pdf$  viewer.php?pdf=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This works well with firefox however chrome chooses to open the pdf in its own in browser embed/displayer. How can I make this work with chrome?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .htaccess to set the mime type, it works better when you use your viewer.php to set the appropriate headers that should work as you want in all browsers.

See the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. However, the problem is I am using wordpress so I cannot just add a prefix before pdf links. Is there a work around?

Comment: You can keep redirecting urls ending in .pdf to viewer.php, exactly like you are doing now. In viewer.php you should just add more http headers to force browsers to download the file instead of opening it in the browser window. The link in my original answer should give you a good start, since it addresses the same problem you have.