# Download Link not working in html

Tags: php, html, css, download

i am trying to make a download link in html that is given like this  for a PDF Book

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.org/pdf/book.pdf" target="_blank"> Download </a>
```

but problem is that when download link is clicked it  opens  online version of pdf , does not offer download ,  i  did google and found same  way to add download link , any one can guide me with it please whats wrong here

Comment: use something like this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this

```
<a href="/pdf/book.pdf" download="book.pdf">Download </a>
```

Comment: i had already tried this but  but thank u for this ,  accepted this as it was the right  ans and  anyone comes later will  be helpful for him

Comment: This is correct. But "download" attribute is only works for resources with in same-origin. right?

Answer (score 14):

As of late 2018, clicking the link won’t trigger a download if the resource to be downloaded wasn’t served from the same origin or same server. Apparently, this is restriction is a security measure.

You can download the content in browser and make it downloadable, you can check the below url

https://medium.com/charisol-community/downloading-resources-in-html5-a-download-may-not-work-as-expected-bf63546e2baa

Comment: I am opening an html page which is in my computer to test donwload links. it doesnt work. html page and file to be downloaded are both in my pc.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 defines the [`download` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download), which forces the browser to prompt the user a download dialog for the resource instead of navigate to it.

Here is the support across the different browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download.

Answer (score 1):

Its not the problem with your script, instead its your browser that has pdf plug-in and displays you the content file directly.You can just save the page (Press CTRL+S) and it would be saved as .PDF file.

Thanks.

Comment: but i cant make my site users to press ctrl +s :)

Comment: If you are willing to use php at back end then do this: `<?php
 $file_data=file_get_contents ("file.pdf");
 header("Content-disposition:attachment;filename=".$file_name);
 echo $file_data;
?>` it will force download....

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 download attribute is only supported by Chrome and firefox...  Try this :

```
<a href="download.php" target="_blank"> Download </a>
```

Download.php

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=http://www.mydomain.org/pdf/book.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/pdf:");
readfile("http://www.mydomain.org/pdf/book.pdf");
```

Comment: i used this and its  working   <a href="http://www.mydomain.org/pdf/book.pdf" target="_blank" download="book name "> Download </a>

Answer (score -1):

if you want to download the pdf in next tab with current website intact then use following code:

```
 <a href="/pdf/book.pdf" download="book.pdf" target="_blank">Download </a>
```