# The download link opens the link instead of downloading it

Tags: html

I used the code:

```
<a download href="https://web.stanford.edu/group/csp/cs21/htmlcheatsheet.pdf"> Download cheetsheat</a>
```

but i wasn't able to make the link download the PDF. It opens the PDF instead.

The attribute is "download" but it is not working

Comment: Add more code in your question. What did you do? What did you expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download Link not working in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300499/download-link-not-working-in-html)

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6794432/4038579

Answer (score 0):

Set the download attribute to the filename:

```
<a download="htmlcheatsheet.pdf" href="https://web.stanford.edu/group/csp/cs21/htmlcheatsheet.pdf"> Download cheetsheat</a>
```