# How do I host a PDF file so a user can click on my "Resume" link and it goes directly to that file for the user to view?

Tags: pdf

So basically what I want is - On my personal website, after the user has clicked the "Resume" link on my navigation, I want it to direct to the PDF file so the user can view my resume through the PDF file. How will I make this work? Do I have to host the file somewhere? How do I generate the link to my PDF file? Please help, thank you .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make PDF file downloadable in HTML link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link)

Answer (score 0):

you can host the file in the same folder you're hosting your website. the link will be, for example, www.yourwebsite.com/myresume.pdf

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10540319)

Comment: @Odedra Are you sure this is not an attempt to answer the (rather trivial) question?