# How can download a pdf in php?

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I try to download a pdf in php but I can do it? Can anyone help me?
I try do it with this code but it doesn't works.

```
$file ="cv0.pdf"; 
$filename = "cv0descargado.pdf"; // el nombre con el que se descargara, puede ser diferente al original 
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"\n"); readfile($file);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make PDF file downloadable in HTML link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: any errors? or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = $_GET["file"];
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode(basename($file)));
    // header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
```

Please try this way

Comment: Yes i search from my machine but cant got so search in google and give answer

Answer (score 0):

## Use php with js:

```
<?php $path = "yourfilepath/name.pdf"; ?>

<button onclick="imageClick('<?php echo $path ?>')">Click</button>

<script>
    function imageClick(url) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.target = "_blank";
    a.href = url;
    a.click();
        }
</script>
```