# Php file download prevent url change

Tags: php, download

I am using this to download file:

```
<a href="download_init.php?Down=01.zip">download here</a>
```

download_init.php:

```
<?php
 $Down=$_GET['Down'];
?>

<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $Down; ?>">
 </head>
<body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Is there a way to prevent browser url changing when clicking on the link without ajax?

```
download_init.php?Down=01.zip
```

Check here: http://www.firegrid.co.uk/scripts/download/index.php

Click on the first link, the url doesnt change, unlike other links.

Comment: Provide `download` attribute to anchor

Comment: i think you can use header() function to download file in download_init.

Comment: That isn't safe to use at all; use a header and hide the file outside the root for better security.

Comment: answer is here .refer  https://perishablepress.com/http-headers-file-downloads/

Answer (score 1):

Add a `download` attribute to anchor tag :

```
<a href="download_init.php?Down=01.zip" download>download here</a>
```

For more detail on [**HTML download Attribute**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

If you want to use `header` please refer [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/364950/3894567)

Comment: if I use download like that, than it just downloads download_init.php file instead of 01.zip

Comment: No.... if you are using another file to download your zip file than you have to use proper headers as mentioned by the @poiz below. If you want to use use download attribute directly with anchor tag than you have to link the actual path of zip file as href.

Comment: my main question was actually is it possible to prevent url change using my method.

Comment: As I answered above... adding the download attribute to anchor tag prevent the url redirection. Just pass the zip file link as href....

Answer (score 1):

You could perform an actual Download using a handful of `header` Functions as depicted in the Code below.

However; first, you may need to create an Arbitrary Processing File (example: `download_init.php`) at the Root of your App. Now inside that `download_init.php` File, you could add something like this:

```
<?php 

// CHECK THAT THE `d` PARAMETER IS SET IN THE GET SUPER-GLOBAL:
// THIS PARAMETER HOLDS THE PATH TO THE DOWNLOAD-FILE...
// IF IT IS SET, PROCESS THE DOWNLOAD AND EXIT...
if(isset($_GET['d']) && $_GET['d']){
    processDownload($_GET['d']);
    exit;
}

function processDownload($pathToDownloadFile, $newName=null) {
    $type               = pathinfo($pathToDownloadFile, 
                                   PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($pathToDownloadFile){
        if(file_exists($pathToDownloadFile)){
            $size       = @filesize($pathToDownloadFile);
            $newName    = ($newName) ? $newName . ".{$type}" :basename($pathToDownloadFile);
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type ($pathToDownloadFile ));
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $newName);
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
            return(readfile($pathToDownloadFile));
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

However, this implies that your Links would now have slightly different `href` values like so:

```
<!-- THIS WOULD TRIGGER THE DOWNLOAD ONCE CLICKED --> 
<a href="download_init.php?d=path_to_01.zip">download here</a>
```

If you find this Header approach too extraneous for your purpose; @Sanchit Gupta provided a Solution with the HTML5 `download` Attribute....