# Download file from a href link, how?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, .net

I have a a tag with href inside. When link is clicked a wanna download a file from my server. How can I do this. Here is my tag

```
"    <a href=\""+ downloadPDF("xxx","xxx") +"\">
```

downloadPDF is a method which starts the download, but how to make the href link call this method?

Comment: You use onclick?

Comment: Does `downloadPDF()` return a string holding the URL?

Comment: <form method="get" action="file.doc">
   <button type="submit">Download!</button>
</form> Do something like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make PDF file downloadable in HTML link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download file when clicking on the link (instead of navigating to the file).

Refer this site : [w3schools-download](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_a_download.asp)

```
Eg:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
     <img border="0" src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="Click here to  Download" width="104" height="142">
  </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `download` attribute in your anchor tag.

Check this https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_a_download.asp.

You can also try `onclick`.