# Download with PHP --> ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: php, http, download, http-headers, content-length

I would like to download a PDF via PHP from my server, which is also uploaded via PHP. Although it works with some files I get the following error message with individual files:

**ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH**

This is my download function:

```
if($_GET['funktion'] == 'downloadverwaltung')
 {


   $filename = basename($dateiname);
   $path = '/kunden/261105_71522/webseiten/admin/PDF/fern_downloads/'.$rowkurs['courseid'].'/'.$filename.''; // the file made available for download via this PHP file

     if($_SESSION['xle'][$_GET['idsh']]['letype'] == 'fern' && $_GET['link'] == 'ja')
        {
         $path = 'http://ls.gdvz.de/'.$filename.'';
        }
     elseif($_SESSION['xle'][$_GET['idsh']]['letype'] == 'fern' && $_GET['link'] != 'ja')
        {
         $path = '/kunden/261105_71522/webseiten/dev.delst/admin/PDF/fern_downloads/'.$_GET['kursid'].'/'.$filename.'';
        }
     elseif($_SESSION['xle'][$_GET['idsh']]['letype'] == 'kurs' && $_GET['link'] == 'ja')
        {
         $path = 'http://ls.gdvz.de/'.$filename.'';
        }
     elseif($_SESSION['xle'][$_GET['idsh']]['letype'] == 'kurs' && $_GET['link'] != 'ja')
        {
         $path = '/kunden/261105_71522/webseiten/dev.delst/pdf/'.$_GET['kursid'].'/'.$filename.'';
        }                

     $check = file_exists($path);
     if( $_GET['link'] == 'ja')
         $check = fopen($path, "r"); 

     //echo $path;
     if ($check) {
            $mm_type="application/octet-stream"; // modify accordingly to the file type of $path, but in most cases no need to do so

            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Cache-Control: public");
            header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
            header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
            header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($path)) );
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

            readfile($path); // outputs the content of the file

            exit();
        }

        else
          echo'Datei wurde nicht auf dem Server gefunden';
 }
```

If I remove **header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($path)) );** the download works, but the PDF file is then broken and can not be opened.

I also tried the following:

```
if($_GET['funktion'] == 'downloadverwaltung')
 {


   $filename = basename($dateiname);
   $path = '/kunden/261105_71522/webseiten/admin/PDF/fern_downloads/'.$rowkurs['courseid'].'/'.$filename.''; // the file made available for download via this PHP file

     if($_SESSION['xle'][$_GET['idsh']]['letype'] == 'fern' && $_GET['link'] == 'ja')
        {
         $path = 'http://ls.gdvz.de/'.$filename.'';
        }
     elseif($_SESSION['xle'][$_GET['idsh']]['letype'] == 'fern' && $_GET['link'] != 'ja')
        {
         $path = '/kunden/261105_71522/webseiten/dev.delst/admin/PDF/fern_downloads/'.$_GET['kursid'].'/'.$filename.'';
        }
     elseif($_SESSION['xle'][$_GET['idsh']]['letype'] == 'kurs' && $_GET['link'] == 'ja')
        {
         $path = 'http://ls.gdvz.de/'.$filename.'';
        }
     elseif($_SESSION['xle'][$_GET['idsh']]['letype'] == 'kurs' && $_GET['link'] != 'ja')
        {
         $path = '/kunden/261105_71522/webseiten/dev.delst/pdf/'.$_GET['kursid'].'/'.$filename.'';
        }                

     //echo $path;
     if (file_exists($path)) {
           // $mm_type="application/octet-stream"; // modify accordingly to the file type of $path, but in most cases no need to do so

           // header("Pragma: public");
           // header("Expires: 0");
           // header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
           // header("Cache-Control: public");
           // header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
           // header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
           // header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($path)) );
           // header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
           // header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

           set_time_limit(0);
           output_file($path, basename($path), 'application/octet-stream');

            exit();
        }

        else
          echo'Datei wurde nicht auf dem Server gefunden';
 }
```

The path is correct and the file is located on the server. So the upload works..

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to increase the Memory Limit with `ini_set ( 'memory_limit', '256M' );`

```
if (file_exists ( $filepath )) {

    header ( 'content-type: application/octet-stream' );
    header ( 'content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary' );
    header ( 'content-length: ' . filesize ( $filepath ) );
    header ( 'content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename ( $filepath ) );

    // setzt temporär die Grenze für den zur Vergügung stehenden Arbeitsspeicher hoch
    ini_set ( 'memory_limit', '256M' );

    ob_clean ();
    ob_flush ();
    flush ();

    readfile ( $filepath );
}
else {
    Throw new Exception ( "Die Datei $filepath konnte nicht gefunden werden" );
}
```

Comment: If I comment out "ini_set('memory_limit', '256M')" the file gets downloaded but can't be opened. I get an alert in the browser that says "Fehler beim Laden des PDF-Documents."

Comment: Is the file valid? Maybe it's already broken after upload. Have a look at both files (Server, Client) in the editor (e.g. Notepad++)

Comment: Yup, the file is valid. If I echo out the path and paste it into the browser, the file gets opened..

Comment: It could be also a problem with encoding (Which OS do you use? Windows saves files in window1252) maybe with filename and german characters

Comment: I'm using windows.. The filename is "Pruefungsordnung_Gepruefter_Betriebswirt_IHK.pdf"

Comment: Did you try to provide a simple Textfile.txt for download? I guess only some error reporting will show you the right direction to fix the problem. sorry I don't have any other idea.

Answer (score 1):

Check here: [How to make PDF file downloadable in HTML link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link)

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$file = $_GET["file"] .".pdf";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
} 
fclose($fp);
```