# Save PDF file as PDF not PHP

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using using FPDF to create pdf file. But it show extension as php not pdf. When i download the file in mobile it show .php file. Now how can I convert the php extension to pdf

Here index.php file

```
 <a href="pdf.php">Click Here</a>
```

Here pdf.php file

```
 <?php
 require ("fpdf/fpdf.php");
 $name = "Amit Samadder";
 $pdf = new FPDF('p','mm','A4');
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","20");
 $pdf->Cell(100,10, $name, 1,0, "C");
 $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm

You need to change this line:

```
$pdf->Output();
```

To:

```
$pdf->Output('D', 'myfile.pdf');
```