# How can i give link to download(not open) pdf file in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

this is my code which i am writing in render method, which works fine, but instead of downloading this file it's opening in browser.

```
<a href="http://www.sites/default/files/2019-01/560_12thMarkSheet.pdf" target="_blank" type="application/pdf; download='some_pdf_name'> length=362340">download</a>
```

How can i give a link in react to force download a file, file which is coming from external server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make PDF file downloadable in HTML link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML5**

```
<a download href="file.pdf">Download PDF</a>
```

Comment: doesn't work if <a href="http://www.sites/default/files/2019-01/560_12thMarkSheet.pdf" target="_blank" type="application/pdf; download='some_pdf_name'> length=362340">download</a>
file is from external server

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a variable names as "link" in which the link is stored. So you can do,

```
    <a href={`${link}`} type="application/pdf; download='some_pdf_name'>Download</a>
```

Comment: this is opening a file (a pdf file) in browser, instead i want it to force download it.