# How to put a downloadable pdf link in html

Tags: html

this is the code i wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="test.txt" download="hi">Click to download!</a>
</body>

</html>
```

when I click on the text I it doesnt download the file and it only previews it instead of downloading
Can you write me a proper code ? thanks

Comment: try `<a href="file link" download target="_blank">Click here to download</a>` use the download attribute to force it as download

Comment: That's a text file, not a PDF, why is your question one thing but code another?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make PDF file downloadable in HTML link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link)

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for pdf file and in link txt file is given..

anyways.. no prob...

try

```
  <a href="test.txt" target='_blank' download>Click to download!</a>
```

Comment: where is test..txt file stored ? in root or in a folder ??