# DocFX - how to place an export to PDF button on header/footer

Tags: docfx

I'd like to place a button on the header/footer of the docfx generated site that is when clicked it downloads an already generated/saved PDF in the asset folder of the site.

Tried to scour the web for documentation on how to go about this but I don't think this is documented that well.

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you should create a new template. DocFX provides a basic tutorial to do so ([here](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/walkthrough/advanced_walkthrough.htmlhttps://)).
In the new template you should copy the *navbar.tmpl.partial* file (resp. *footer.tmpl.partial*) in the *_exported_templates/default/partials/* folder to modify the header (resp. footer). In these, you can add an anchor section as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link).
You will have less trouble modifying the footer who is "pasted" as it is in the master layout (The navbar is populated using javascript).

Don't forget to apply the new template in your *docfx.json* file.